# The textbox1.Text can't copy the textbox2.Text value from another form

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

Below is my code

```
private void btnCptKb5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   Form1 form1 = new Form1();
   textbox1.text = form1.textbox1.text;
}
```

Why is that I can't copy the value of form1 textbox?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. What do you mean by not being able to copy?

Comment: Because you just created a brand new form with no data.

Comment: You've created the form but done nothing else - what are you expecting to copy? Have you populated the textbox with a value?

Comment: I think...the above code won't compile, do you want to say Form1 form1 = new Form1()? By the way, form1 is a new object which contains no data

Comment: sorry for my english. the btnCptKb5_Click is from form 2 and I want to copy the value I inputted from form1 textbox? How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You didn't change `Textbox2.Text` value
- You are creating a completely new form instance,and trying to access that form's textbox value.It will be always empty even if your code works.
- I think This question is most commonly asked question in StackOverflow  You can take a look at these questions, and I'm sure you will find an appropriate answer:

  1) [How to pass values between forms in c# windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205195/how-to-pass-values-between-forms-in-c-sharp-windows-application)

  2) [Passing data between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms)

  3) [switching between forms without loss of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333644/switching-between-forms-without-loss-of-information)

  4) [windows.form c# moving between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250350/windows-form-c-sharp-moving-between-forms)

  5) [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

  6) [How to share data between forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800603/sharing-data-between-forms)

  7) [Passing Data Between Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464625/passing-data-between-forms)

  8) [Get data from one textbox on form1 from another textbox on form2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869899/get-data-from-one-textbox-on-form1-from-another-textbox-on-form2/20869998#20869998)