# How do you transfer variables between forms in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

I was just wondering exactly how you transfer string and integer variables between forms. Example on what I mean would be having the user input their name and age which would transfer and show in another form and have this be activated by a button.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions asking this. I am voting to close this because it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is around here somewhere:

1) [How to pass values between forms in c# windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205195/how-to-pass-values-between-forms-in-c-sharp-windows-application)

2) [Passing data between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587952/passing-data-between-forms)

3) [switching between forms without loss of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333644/switching-between-forms-without-loss-of-information)

4) [windows.form c# moving between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250350/windows-form-c-sharp-moving-between-forms)

5) [Communicate between two windows forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

6) [How to share data between forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800603/sharing-data-between-forms)

7) [Passing Data Between Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464625/passing-data-between-forms)

8) [Get data from one textbox on form1 from another textbox on form2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869899/get-data-from-one-textbox-on-form1-from-another-textbox-on-form2/20869998#20869998)

Comment: I don't know who down voted this, but I think this is a good answer that shows it is a duplicate question. One of these is going to give the poster a cut and paste answer for their particular code.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using Simple [Events and delegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4773/Events-and-Delegates-Simplified) concept. Publish event from your `Form 1` and you can subscribe that in your `Form 2` page. `Delegate` will be act as a communication channel between `Event` and `Event handler`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Global static class for saving values. And just use the object of that class at the another location.And create new object of the class whenever the task is completed.

Comment: This is generally considered bad practice. Software should always be designed around the idea of least privilege. So giving global access to a variable when only one form needs it is not a good idea. See one of the other linked answers that uses delegate methods or any number of other ways of directly communicating between forms.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the values from the main form to the child form using public properties.

Something like

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm c = new ChildForm();
        c.StringValue = "TADA";
        c.IntValue = 42;
        c.Show();
    }
}


public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public string StringValue{get; set;}
    public int IntValue { get; set; }

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```